# May I use jQuery-File-Upload to extract exif data after fileupload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, exif, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I know there is a solution out there to do that using other library and to do it before upload. But the question is if this functionality is already in jQuery-File-Upload and if yes how can I use it after the image is successfully uploaded. I tried to dig through the source code of jQuery-File-Upload but, honestly, it's a very hard for a JS beginner like me.

Comment: You are mean you want to using JS and AJAX to upload files?

Comment: I already know how to upload the file. I wonder if I can use same jQuery-File-Upload library to extract the exif data from the image. Perhaps I phrased the question badly. Is it at all possible? Or do you I need to extract exif data before actually uploading the file and do I need some other library to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out myself.

Use *processdone* callback and access *exif* object of *data*, e.g.:

```
    processdone(e, data) {
      data.exif
    }
```